# pyxll return array of strings

Tags: python, sql, arrays, string, pyxll

I'm creating a xl_func that receives data from sql server (string) and return to excel (auto_resize=True). The end of the code is:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
final_result = [row[0] for row in result]
return final_result
```

It runs okay, but it returns each character in a different column.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
final_result = [row[0:1] for row in result]
return final_result
```